# Creating a SQL Table with Composite Primary Key alone

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a SQL table to store a customer id and zipcode, only these 2 columns. Combination of these 2 values makes a row unique. I have 3 options in mind but not sure which one would be efficient. I will store around 200000 rows in this table and the read operation is high and write will happen once in a day.

Select query will get all customers based on the input zipcode.

example:
`Select customerid from dbo.customerzipcode where zipcode in (<multiple zipcodes>)`

Option 1:

- Create a table with 2 columns (customerid and zipcode)
- Create a composite primary key for these 2 columns.

Option 2:

- Create a table with 3 columns (id, customerid and zipcode)
- id being identity and primary key
- create a unique constraint for customerid and zipcode

Option 3:

- Create a table with 3 columns (id, customerid and zipcode)
- Create a non clustered index for zipcode alone.

Can you please share which option would be better?

Comment: Your "slippery slope" shows up when you try to create a FK to this table.  If you use the compositite-key (2 columns here)..if you FK to this table.....you will have to put 2 columns in the "other" table.  Thus why most defer to Option 2 I think.  And (bonus)...if you create a unique-constraint-today...but in the future....you need to "loosen" the constraint (customers might have 2 addresses).... you only have to alter the unique constraint.  Much easier than a table rerestructure.

Comment: There's not enough info for a correct answer - does this table relate with or join to other tables? how are the inserts handled, ad-hoc or batches? In hours or out of hours?  *Possibly* consider adding an identiy and clustered primary key on `customerID, Id` and nonclustered index on `Zipcode`; If you never query for the customer Id and do not join on it then instead clustered primary key would be `Zipcode, CustomerId`

Comment: Hi granadaCoder and Stu, Thanks for the responses. what you said is right if I have to refer this table as a foreign key then I will have a trouble. This table will not act as a reference for any other table. Also, customerId to zipcode will be unique. Also, I don't have a join condition now. I think the last point from Stu would work.

Comment: I like my clustered indexes to follow the natural insertion order. Are customerIDs always increasing? Then clustered PK can be customerID, Zipcode. You can have a separate NON-unique index on zipcode to support searching users by zipcodes.

Comment: Hi @siggemannen, customerid is a string and the record count may not increase frequently. I thought of this option of having a nonclustered fot zipcode alone. I have to check. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Select customerid from dbo.customerzipcode where zipcode in ()

The canonical design would have an index with each column as the leading column to support efficient lookup by zipcode or by customerid, eg

```
create table customerzipcode
(
  zipcode varchar(10) not null,
  customerid int not null references customer,
  constraint pk_customerzipcode primary key (zipcode,customerid),
  index ix_customerzip_customerid (customerid)
)
```

Comment: Thanks @David Browne. I will implement this approach and test the performance of the application.

Comment: Hi @David Browne, I tried this option and the select query performance was good but the inserting the data from my spring application takes more time. Insert took more than 40 min for 42k records.

Comment: Something else is going on.  That’s way too slow.

Comment: Hi, yes.. I created the table with a primary key column which is a sequence and then created customerid and postcodes as a unique non clustered index. Now the insert worked fast and insert for 200k records completed in less than 5 minutes. I am testing the query part.